# Is there a way to show 2 confirmation messages inside my Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application and i am using `Ajax.ActionLink` to do a delete operation :-

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete","Delete", "Server",
new { id = item.ID },

new AjaxOptions
{   Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete ?",
    HttpMethod = "Post",

    OnSuccess = "deletionconfirmation",
    OnFailure = "deletionerror"
})
```

now i am trying to achieve the following , is that after the user click OK on the first confirmation message , to show another confirmation message.. to make sure that the user want to delete the record ...so is this possible ?

Comment: Are you making **GET** method to perform delete action? If so, please do not do that; it is a very bad practice. Delete should be either **POST** or **DELETE** Http verb.

Comment: @Win as mentioned on my code i am specifying HttpMethod = "Post" so it is a post request not a get request !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OnBegin Method of AjaxOptions
    OnBegin="return functionname"
And then 
    return false in the functionname method will prevent it from deleting

Comment: OnBegin will show the dialog ,but the onBegin dialog will not prevent calling the delete action method ... did you try it from your side ?

Comment: See the edit code.Basically add a return before function name and prevent it by returning false;otherwise true

Comment: now i define the following  OnBegin="secondConfirm" and this function function secondConfirm() {
    confirm("Press a button!");
    return false;
} .. but what is happening is that when the user click on the ajax.actinolink a confirm will be shown,, then the OnBegin confirmation will be shown also... but if the user confirm the OnBegin dialog ,, the deletion will not proceed ... not sure how i can fix this ?

Comment: Confirm button returns true if ok is clicked otherwise false. What is should do is add this code in your OnBegin method and remove confirm attribute from your code: if(confirm("Confirm deletion?")){ return true;} else return false; I think that is what you want